# Is Nested Structure with Spread Responsibilities Not Logical?

Tags: object-oriented, php, dependency-management, laravel, method-chaining

Given the following code snippet in a Laravel Controller:

```
$this->userRepository->saveByProject(
    $this->fileRepository->saveByProject(
        $this->metricRepository->saveByProject(
            $this->projectRepository->saveByUser(
                $request->attributes->get('user'), $request->all(), $id
            ),
            $request->input('metrics')
        ),
        $request->input('files') ?? []
    ),
    $request->input('contact') ?? []
);
```

As you can see, each first parameter should be a 'Project' (an object that implements the interface 'Project').

## Doubtful Point

The doubtful point is the method 'saveByProject' in each repository. In userRepository for example, it saves the user and the relation between user and given project, and returns the project with the related user. I hope you understand the construction. You know this works too for files (FileRepository), etc.

## Pros and Cons of the Solution Above

Pros:

- Less dependencies in ProjectRepository
- Less procedural, because it's one statement
- Readable, but other than "logical"

Cons:

- Multiple repositories with method 'saveByProject'
- Less readable in comparison with method chaining

## Alternative : Method Chaining

Pros:

- More readable
- FileRepository and other repositories know nothing about Project

Cons:

- ProjectRepository has many dependencies (see code snippet below)
- ProjectRepository has many methods

Code snippet:

```
$this->projectRepository->saveProject(
    $request->attributes->get('user'), $request->all(), $id
)
->saveFiles($request->input('files')) // call FileRepository
->saveMetrics($request->input('metrics')); // call MetricRepository
```

//etc.

Each save* method calls the right repository, but *handles saving the relation with the project by itself*, and returns the project.

Comment: I am trying really hard to figure out what the actual function of the `saveByProject` method is and I cannot do it. Could you maybe describe it in more detail? Or even better, what is the general functionality you desire to have.

Comment: Ok, saveByProject() saves the given data by the given project instance. For example: the metric repository saves the metrics and the relation between the passed project instance and the saved metrics. The user repository saves the contact and the relation between the passed project instance and the saved contact. So the repository doesn't know the project (or is not related to), but only the method saveByProject expects a project instance and returns a "enriched" project instance.